# Who was the first comic book artist to use Toad's slime in comics after the first X-Men film was released?

Tags: marvel, x-men, toads-spit

When Toad first appeared in the X-Men back in 1964, his only mutant ability involved super-strong legs that allowed him to leap great distances. As the years went by, his mutation was enhanced and he gained a prehensile tongue, among other mutations.

When the first X-Men film was released, he displayed the ability to spit an adhesive slime, which he used on Jean Grey, nearly suffoating her to death. While this was the first time Toad had displayed this power, it migrated over into comics. My question is who was the first artist to do this? Any and all input is appreciated.

Comment: Are you still around and interested in an answer?

Answer (score 7):

The first mention of it I've found is *[Wolverine (2nd series) #167](http://uncannyxmen.net/comics/issue/wolverine-2nd-series-167)*. Salvador Larroca was the Penciler, Danny Miki was the Inker, and Liquid! was the Colorist.

[image: Patch vs Toad]

> Before Logan can attack first, Toad delivers a kick to Logan’s face and retreats through a hole in the cage and into the bottom cage. When Logan gives chase and reaches the floor of the bottom cage, Toad spits a sticky green substance into his face. Peeling it from his skin with his claws, Logan tells Toad that was disgusting. Toad replies that he’s sorry he doesn’t approve, perhaps this ability will be more to his liking.

Comment: Cool. Do you know of any of the other X-Men Toad has used his slime on? Besides Jean Grey,, of course.

Comment: @Xfan25: No idea. :)